# oracle dates group

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How to get optimized query for this

```
date_one   | date_two 
------------------------
01.02.1999 | 31.05.2003
01.01.2004 | 01.01.2010
02.01.2010 | 10.10.2011 
11.10.2011 | (null)
```

I need to get this

```
date_one   | date_two   | group 
------------------------------------
01.02.1999 | 31.05.2003 | 1
01.01.2004 | 01.01.2010 | 2
02.01.2010 | 10.10.2011 | 2
11.10.2011 | (null)     | 2
```

The group number is assigned as follows. Order the rows by `date_one` ascending. First row gets `group = 1`. Then for each row if `date_one` is the date immediately following `date_two` of the previous row, the `group` number stays the same as in the `previous` row, otherwise it increases by one.

Comment: Can you please try re-explaining your logic?  It's not as obvious as you think...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `left join` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, sum(case when tprev.date_one is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by t.date_one) as grp
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.date_one = tprev.date_two + 1;
```

The idea is to find where the gaps begin (using the left join) and then do a cumulative sum of such beginnings to define the group.

If you want to be more inscrutable, you could write this as:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (order by t.date_one) - count(tprev.date_one) over (order by t.date_one) as grp
from t left join
     t tprev
     on t.date_one = tprev.date_two + 1;
```

Comment: Analytic functions were created with the specific purpose of avoiding joins where they are not otherwise needed.

Comment: @mathguy . . . A left join here could outperform a window function.  This is an extremely viable solution for the problem.  Note that this is an *equality* join.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using window function:

```
select
  date_one,
  date_two,
  sum(x) over (order by date_one) grp
from (
    select
        t.*,
        case when 
        lag(date_two) over (order by date_one) + 1 =
            date_one then 0 else 1 end x
    from t
);
```

It finds the date_two from the last row using analytic function `lag` and check if it in continuation with date_one from this row (in increasing order of date_one).

#### How it works:

```
lag(date_two) over (order by date_one)
```

(*In the below explanation, when I say first, next, previous or last row, it's based on increasing order of date_one with null values at the end*)

The above produces produces `NULL` for the first row as there is no row before it to get date_two from and previous row's date_two for the subsequent rows.

```
case when 
      lag(date_two) 
      over (order by date_one) + 1 = date_one then 0
     else 1 end
```

Since, the lag produces `NULL` for the very first row (since `NULL = anything` expression always finally evaluates to false), output of case will be 1.

For further rows, similar check will be done to produce a new column `x` in the query output which has value 1 when the previous row's date_two is not in continuation with this row's date_one.

Then finally, we can do an incremental sum on `x` to find the required group values. See the value of x below for understanding:

```
SQL> with t (date_one,date_two) as (
  2     select to_date('01.02.1999','dd.mm.yyyy'),to_date('31.05.2003','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
 all
  3     select to_date('01.01.2004','dd.mm.yyyy'),to_date('01.01.2010','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
 all
  4     select to_date('02.01.2010','dd.mm.yyyy'),to_date('10.10.2011','dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
 all
  5     select to_date('11.10.2011','dd.mm.yyyy'),null from dual
  6  )
  7  select
  8    date_one,
  9    date_two,
 10    x,
 11    sum(x) over (order by date_one) grp
 12  from (
 13     select
 14             t.*,
 15             case when
 16             lag(date_two) over (order by date_one) + 1 =
 17                     date_one then 0 else 1 end x
 18     from t
 19  );

DATE_ONE  DATE_TWO           X        GRP
--------- --------- ---------- ----------
01-FEB-99 31-MAY-03          1          1
01-JAN-04 01-JAN-10          1          2
02-JAN-10 10-OCT-11          0          2
11-OCT-11                    0          2

SQL>
```

Comment: In all problems like this, it is best - when you explain how it works - to also explain the "boundary cases." In this example, what happens for the first row? Answer - in that case `lag()` returns `null`, so the `when` condition in the `case` expression in the subquery is not satisfied, so the flag `x` gets the value `1`, which is what's needed for this to work.